# Using $project to return an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents which look like this:

```js
{
    "campaignType" : 1,
    "allowAccessControl" : true,
    "userId" : "108028399"
}
```

I'd like to query this collection using aggregation framework and have a result which looks like this:

```js
{
    "campaignType" : ["APPLICATION"],
    "allowAccessControl" : "true",
    "userId" : "108028399",
}
```

You will notice that:

- `campaignType` field becomes and array
- the numeric value was mapped to a string

Can that be done using aggregation framework?

I tried looking at `$addToSet` and `$push` but had no luck.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either case here it is th [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator from the aggregation framework that is your friend. It is a "ternary" operator, which means it evaluates a condition for `true|false` and then returns the result based on that evaluation.

So for modern versions from MongoDB 2.6 and upwards you can [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with usage of the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator to construct the array:

```js
db.campaign.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "campaignType": {
            "$map": {
                "input": { "$literal": [1] },
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$campaignType", 1 ] },
                        "APPLICATION",
                        false
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "allowAcessControl" : 1,
        "userId": 1
    }}
])
```

Or generally in most versions you can simply use the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) operator in a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage:

```js
db.campaign.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "campaignType": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                     { "$eq": [ "$campaignType", 1 ] },
                     "APPLICATION",
                     false
                 ]
            }
        },
        "allowAccessControl": { "$first": "$allowAccessControl" },
        "userId": { "first": "$userId" }
    }}
])
```

But the general concept if that you use "nested" expressions with the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator in order to "test" and return some value that matches your "mapping" condition and do that with another operator that allows you to produce an array.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I'm using Talend and thus forced to use mongo 2.5.. 

I'm wondering what is the meaning of 
'{ "$first": "$allowAccessControl" }'? Again - thanks a lot!

Comment: @Leo The [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator is a "grouping operator" in the aggregation API. It returns the "first" match within the "grouping key" specified in `_id` for that pipeline stage. BTW MongoDB 2.5 as with most verisoning  systems means a "development" revision since the minor version is an odd number. Any production code that depends on a "development" release is unreliable.